# Way to block CascadingValue or exclude component from EditContext in Blazor?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor

What I'm trying to fix: I'm encountering a problem when using some DevExpress Blazor components inside of an `EditForm`, they do not work. I believe this is because the `EditForm` provides an `EditContext` as a CascadingValue and when this is present the Dx controls require a `ValueExpression` or `CheckedExpression`, etc. to be set. One example is trying to enable a column-chooser for a grid that is inside of an `EditForm`:

https://demos.devexpress.com/blazor/Grid/Columns#ColumnChooser

When I try to open the column chooser, I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: DevExpress.Blazor.DxCheckBox requires a value for the 'CheckedExpression' property.

Here is a simple example illustrating this:

```
<EditForm Model="data">
    <input type="number" @bind-value="data.Id" />
    <DxCheckBox
        T="bool"
        Checked="unrelatedValue" 
        CheckedChanged="b => unrelatedValue = b">
    </DxCheckBox>
</EditForm>

@code {
    private DataObject data = new DataObject();

    private bool unrelatedValue;

    public class DataObject
    {
        public int? Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If the `DxCheckBox` is moved outside of the `EditForm`, the error doesn't occur.

Is there any way to block a CascadingValue or otherwise exclude a component from an `EditContext` so that it doesn't require the `Expression` property be set?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/403285/troubleshooting/editor-related-issues/system-argument-null-exception-requires-a-value-for-the-expression-property), if you don't use two way binding, then you need to provide the ValueExpression.

Given that the values you have set for Checked and CheckedChanged would would fine with two-way binding, then I'd go for that:

```
@bind-Checked=@unrelatedValue
```

Otherwise, add a ValueExpression:

```
ValueExpression=@(() => unrelatedValue)
```

Comment: The problem is when I use third party components (like the DxGrid column chooser mentioned in the question) that contain these editors with no `CheckedExpression` defined. I have no control over that.

Comment: I see.  My code would fix the sample you provided, but I see that the DxGrid creates it's own Column Chooser.  Hmmm.  Looks like they may have assumed putting a grid inside an EditForm was not a valid use case.

Answer (score 0):

Although this does not directly answer the question, I've had multiple issues here as well with DevExpress comoponents - after LOTS of digging, I found out you should provide the `ValueExpression`/`CheckedExpression`/`TextExpression` if binding is not default... Here a working example for a spin-edit:

```
<DxSpinEdit Value="@EditingItem.IntValue"  ValueChanged="@((newValue) => { EditingItem.IntValue = newValue; HandleFormSubmit(); })"
            ValueExpression="@(() => EditingItem.IntValue)" />
```